# Java HttpClient: I keep getting login page back when I request a different webpage even after I had already logged in successfully

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

My goal:

- Post Login
- Get Image (link) within that same session and post it

So far:

- I login via HttpPost and save cookie:

---

```
private String sessionId = ""; 


....

private int loginToServer() throws IOException
{
    int result = 0;
    String httpsURL = "http://192.168.1.100:8080/foo/login.jsp";
    HttpResponse response;
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpClientContext httpContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    try 
    {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(httpsURL);
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();

        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "*****"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "*****"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost,httpContext);

        //store cookies
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        cookieStore = httpContext.getCookieStore();
        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null)
        {
            for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
            {
               sessionId = cookie.getValue();                   
            }
        }
        result = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return result;
}
```

- I get HTTP/1.1 200 OK:

---

```
POST /mysubdir/login.jsp HTTP/1.1

Content-Length: 33

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 192.168.2.100:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_25)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

username=******&password=******HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=97D93F7C7E11F22A6E895554E761D3AE; Path=/foo/;    HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 13:21:18 GMT

2000

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Hoarder Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="resource/favicon.ico"></link>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body {
 .margin: 0;
 .padding: 0;
 .overflow: hidden;
}
.....
```

- I send a Get Request:

---

```
private InputStream sendGet(String url) {
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response  = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try 
    {

        //Setting up cookie store
        CookieStore cookiestr = new BasicCookieStore(); 
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId);
        cookie.setDomain("192.168.1.100");
        cookie.setPath("/foo/");
        cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.PATH_ATTR, "/foo/");
        cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "192.168.1.100");


        CookieStore cookiestr = httpContext.getCookieStore();
        cookiestr.addCookie(cookie);
        httpContext.setCookieStore(cookiestr);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient =  HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(cookiestr).build();

        httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); 
        is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine());
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return is;
}
```

- the response I get is the login page:

---

```
GET /foo/images/B0DF3A14706A-008-0008/7.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.8.0_25)
Cookie: JSESSIONID=97D93F7C7E11F22A6E895554E761D3AE
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D94C9147870EE8A7DEEDB67AD77B695E; Path=/foo/;     HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 18:28:02 GMT

2000

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<title>Hoarder Login</title>
<link rel="icon" href="resource/favicon.ico"></link>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body {
 .margin: 0;
 .padding: 0;
 .overflow: hidden;
}
......
```

Why am I getting this? I can even see that I am sending with the request is for the same session as the login. Anyone has had this problem? and has anyone came up with a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar experience. The cookie is probably getting rejected by HttpClient. I solved it with this code:

```
        ...

        CookieSpecProvider easySpecProvider = new CookieSpecProvider() {

            public CookieSpec create(HttpContext context) {

                return new BrowserCompatSpec() {
                    @Override
                    public void validate(Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                            throws MalformedCookieException {
                        // Oh, I am easy
                    }
                };
            }

        };

        registry = RegistryBuilder.<CookieSpecProvider>create()
                .register("easy", easySpecProvider)
                .build();

        closableClient = httpclient.setDefaultCookieSpecRegistry(registry).setDefaultRequestConfig(httpRequestBase.getConfig()).build();

        response = closableClient.execute(httpRequestBase, context);

        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @john! Excuse my ignorance, but I have a few questions: Do I implement this method in my POST request (login), so I can save the cookie from the response? What are the types of registry, closableClient and httpRequestBase? Thank you